# Android:About listview's item color

Tags: android, listview

I add a listview and add some textview into it.
In the listview's `OnItemCLickListener` I wanna change the textColor , then problems come:When I change the text color by `setTextColor(Color.BLACK)` ,the item will change to black;But when I change the color by `setTextColor(R.color.mycolor)` , all the items' color will change ! I cannot understand why?
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTextColor(int)` expects a "color integer", not a "resource integer". Try doing this instead:

```
    setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));
```

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Check your code and make sure you're calling setTextColor on just one specific instance in your list. That's the best help I can give you without having some code to go on.